# .find() jQuery not working in tables

Tags: php, jquery

```
<tr id="<?php echo $id?>">
                        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id?>"/>
                        <td> <?php echo $id;?> </td>
                        <td id="fname"> <?php echo $firstname[$key];?> </td>
                        <td id="lname"> <?php echo $lastname[$key];?> </td>
                        <td id="tage"> <?php echo $age[$key];?> </td>
                        </tr>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.edit').click (function(){
        var id = $(this).parent().data('id'); 
        var fname =  $('#id').find('#fname');
        alert(fname);
    });
```

Want to get the text inside `<td>`

In alert it returns an object.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: An aside: I would advise using classes instead of IDs for the cells. IDs are generally supposed to be unique.

Comment: where is `.data('id')` being set? there are no `data-` attributes in html shown. For that matter, there is no `class=edit` in html either

Comment: edited the `#id` it should be an id

Comment: @winona - Well it would still fail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using a `string` instead of an jquery `object` for your selector.

```
$(id).find('#fname')
```

You might consider this, if the value you're retrieving is that of an id, so it will need the hash to be a valid selector:

```
 $('#' + id).find('#fname')
```

Also, valid markup requires id's to be unique on the page.